# Remote Control for audio doesn't work

Tags: ios, events, audio, controls, mpmovieplayercontroller

after I managed to play audio in background with MPMoviePlayerController and tried to make it receive remote controls. But when I click on the Play/Pause button there's no reaction and the audio keeps on playing.
Then I tried to show if there's a log-output but there's no output.

Here's my Code:

```
   -(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
...
       [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
        [self becomeFirstResponder];
    }

    - (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
        [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
        [self resignFirstResponder];
    }

    - (void)remoteControlReceivedWithEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
        NSLog(@"remoteControlReceivedWithEvent: %@", event);
        if (event.type==UIEventTypeRemoteControl) {
            if (event.subtype==UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlPlay) {
                NSLog(@"Play");
            } else if (event.subtype==UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlPause) {
                NSLog(@"Pause");
            } else if (event.subtype==UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlTogglePlayPause) {
                NSLog(@"Play Pause");
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks for your effort in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your view controller isn't in the responder chain.
That might be due to [self resignFirstResponder] in viewWillDisappear and/or another ViewController is in the front.

To make sure you receive these events you can implement a UIApplication subclass which will be able to receive the events always. So it doesn't matter which ViewController is visible.
The UIApplication is always in the end of the responder chain.

Create a subclass for UIApplication (MyUIApplication) and implements the following UIResponder methods:

```
- (void)remoteControlReceivedWithEvent: (UIEvent *) receivedEvent {
    ...
}

- (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder {
  return YES;
}
```

In main.m use the following to initiate the app (replace MyUIApplication and AppDelegate with your classes names):

```
@autoreleasepool {
      return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, NSStringFromClass([MyUIApplication class]), NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
}
```